Amphp асинхронное выполнение функций
Собственно, берем последнюю версию amphp, и очень не понятно, как сдлелать асинхронное выполнение разных функций. В проекте функции выполняют разный функционал, бывает, долго, хотелось выполнить их параллельно, и получить в конце результат.
Помогите правильно написать. К примеру, есть функции:
function asyncTask1() {
    sleep(4);
    return "asyncTask1 completed after 4 seconds.";
}

И
function asyncTask2() {
    sleep(4);
    return "asyncTask2 completed after 4 seconds.";
}

async(function() { asyncTask1(); })->await();
async(function() { asyncTask2(); })->await();

Это конечно же эффекта не даст, потому что, как понимаю, await будет ждать окончания выполнения каждой из функций.
Поэтому вопрос знатокам - как выполнить данные функции асинхронно, и в конце получить ответ от каждой, в данном случае, через 4 секунды?

Использовать delay() вероятно, как пишут в мануале https://amphp.org/installation#hello-world

Это все, конечно, да. Но к примеру, у меня есть куски кода с блокирующим функциями. Как понимаю, в таком случае невозможно запустить две функции в работу параллельно?

Видимо нет, раз функции блокирующие.
